# Galois condition for splitting prime ideals

Tags: galois-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am reading about splitting of prime ideals in Galois extensions. At the beginning, many authors set up AKLBG as follows. Let $A$ be a Dedekind domain, $L/K$ is a finite separable extension of its fraction field $K$, and $B$ is the integral closure of $A$ in $L$, also a Dedekind domain. Assume that the extension $L/K$ is normal, hence Galois, and let $G:=Gal(L/K)$ to denote the Galois group.

Many results are based on the following theorem

> Assume AKLBG and for each fractional ideal $I$ of $B$ and $\sigma \in G$, let $\sigma(I):=\{\sigma(x): x \in I\}$. The set $\sigma(I)$ is a fractional ideal of $B$, and this defines a left $G$-action on $\mathcal{I}_B$ that commutes with the group operation and restricts to a group on prime ideals.

On the proof of the above theorem, ref [MIT](https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.785/2017fa/LectureNotes7.pdf), I don't know where the Galois condition is used.

Comment: Good observation. As far as I can see, the proof does not use the Galois (normality) hypothesis - I think you could replace $G$ by $\mathrm{Aut}_{K}(L)$ everywhere and be fine. (I suspect the Galois condition is of greater importance later on, with (e.g.) the decomposition group.)

Comment: It is used when arguing: $\sigma(b)$ is integral over $A$ hence in $B$ because $B$ is the integral closure of $A$ in $L$. For that to work, $\sigma(b)$ must be in $L$. So the whole point is just that you need $\sigma$ to go from $L$ to $L$, which is probably used a couple other times. As the other commenter writes, that means the argument will still work if you just use automorphisms of $L$ fixing $K$.